# Multiple post IDs from array in Wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I want to display 3 specifics posts.

**Problem :** My posts IDs are from a previous array.

**Result :** It displays only the first one.

**Function :**

```
foreach($fav_author_list as $i => $item) {
  $insert = get_user_favorites($item);
  if (!is_array($insert[0])) {
    $result = array_merge($result, $insert);
  }
}
$algoid = implode(",", $result);
```

Result from $algoid (Post ID) = 865, 866, 877

I want to display the three posts.

```
$myarray = array($algoid);
$args = array(
   'post__in'      => $myarray,
);
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to implode your `$algoid` for the `post__in`. Since you're using `implode`, you're actually passing an array with a string for your query:

```
array('865, 866, 877'); // Items: 1
```

However, WP_Query is expecting an array with the ids, not as a string:

```
array(865, 866, 877); // Items: 3
```

Here's how it should be:

```
// Use your function to generate the array with the IDs
$algoid = array(865, 866, 877); 

$args = array(
    'post__in' => $algoid
);
```

For more information about `WP_Query`: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

> post__in (**array**) - use post ids. Specify posts to retrieve. ATTENTION If you use sticky posts, they will be included (prepended!) in the posts you retrieve whether you want it or not. To suppress this behaviour use ignore_sticky_posts.

Comment: Working ! Thank you